# multiselect dropdown with checkbox in javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
I am using below code for dropdown

    @if (ViewBag.EventContentTypeId == Convert.ToInt32(EventContentType.Events))
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group input" style="padding-left:0">
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.DropDownList("EventCategoryDDL", @ViewBag.EventCategories as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

I want to change these to multi-select dropdown with checkbox.

And this is my controller code and this is in selectlist and i am unable to modify to multiselectlist is their a way to change to multiselectlist of selectlist. 

 ViewBag.EventCategories = ViewBag.EventContentTypeName == EventContentTypeString.Events.Value ? _commonService.GetEventCategoriesModel().Where(category =>category.OptionText != "Camp Kaufmann")
                                           .Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                           {
                                               Text = i.OptionText,
                                               Value = i.OptionValue.ToString()
                                           }) :
                                           _commonService.GetEventCategoriesModel()
                                           .Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                           {
                                               Text = i.OptionText,
                                               Value = i.OptionValue.ToString()
                                           });
```

And how should i change to multiselectlist in my controller side and also how to bind dropdown with check boxes of multiselct.

Comment: That's not Javascript, it's some kind of framework. Please tag your question with the appropriate framework name.

Comment: I guess it's ASP.NET?

Comment: yes its a  ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna simply display checkboxes for each item in your @ViewBag.EventCategories then,

```
@if (ViewBag.EventContentTypeId == Convert.ToInt32(EventContentType.Events))
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3 form-group input" style="padding-left:0">
            <div class="input-group">

                var eventCat = @ViewBag.EventCategories;  
                foreach(var item in eventCat){
                    <input type="checkbox" class="event-category" />
                }

                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

you will have to assign proper values,ids and classes.